# epsilon-delta proof help

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this question,

Let $g$, $f$ be real-valued functions and let $a,l,m \in\mathbb R$.
If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \inf} g(x)=l$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\inf} f(x)=m$, 
then give a complete $N$-$\varepsilon$ prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\inf} (g(x)-af(x))=l-am$

I know that $f(x)-g(x)=(f-g)(x)$ and if $f(x)=y$ then $a*f(x)=a*y$,
but how do I use them to help me prove this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given an $\epsilon \gt 0$. We want to show that
$$|(g(x)-af(x))-(l-am)|\lt \epsilon\tag{1}$$ 
if $x$ is big enough.

We know that we can make $|g(x)-l|$ small by taking $x$ very big, and that we can make $|f(x)-m|$ small by taking $x$ very big. We need to use this information about $f$ and $g$ to get information about the left-hand side of (1).

Note that 
$$|(g(x)-af(x))-(l-am)|=|g(x)-l -a(f(x)-m)|\le |g(x)-l| +|a||f(x)-m|.\tag{2}$$
Here we have used the Triangle Inequality.

If $x$ is chosen so that each  of $|g(x)-l|$ and $|a||f(x)-m|$ is less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then the Inequality (1) will follow.

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=l$, there is a $B_1$ such that if $x\gt B_1$, then
$|g(x)-l|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

If $a=0$, then $|a||f(x)-m|$ will always be less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So suppose that $a\ne 0$. Then since $f(x)$ has limit $M$, there is a $B_2$ such that if $x\gt B_2$, then $|f(x)-m|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2|a|}$. For such $x$, we will have $|a||f(x)-m|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Now let $B$ be the larger of $B_1$ and $B_2$. If $x\gt B$, then the inequalities $|g(x)-l|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a||f(x)-m|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ both hold, and therefore Inequality (1) holds. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall \epsilon_1>0 \exists M_1 \forall X>M_1: |g(x)-l|<\epsilon_1$$
$$\forall \epsilon_2>0 \exists M_2 \forall X>M_2: |f(x)-m|<\epsilon_2$$

Given $\epsilon>0$ take $\epsilon_1=\epsilon/3$ and $\epsilon_2=\frac{\epsilon}{3|a|}$ then by definition exists $M1>0$ and $M_2>0$ with the next property:
$$\forall X>M_1: |g(x)-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$
$$\forall X>M_2: |f(x)-m|<\frac{\epsilon}{3|a|}$$

If you take $M=max\{M_1,M2\}$ then both inequalities are valid for $x>M$, applying both for the next:

$$|g(x)-af(x)-l-am|=|(g(x)-l)-a(f(x)-m)|\leq|(g(x)-l)|+|a||(f(x)-m)|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{3}+|a|\frac{\epsilon}{3|a|}=\frac{2\epsilon}{3}<\epsilon$$

Would leave the desired result $\forall X>M$